# SqlScrip-Hana Studio Procesure para etiquetas

Tags: sql, script

Ya tengo un procedimiento para generar etiquetas la cual funciona bien. Hasta tengo picos de las cantidades, es decir, si la cantidad es 16 y la unidad de empaque 12 entonces imprime una etiqueta y luego otra por las 4 unidades restantes

*¿Cómo puedo hacer para juntar todos estos picos y armar una nueva etiqueta?*

Espero haber sido un poco clara, cualquier idea la agradezco de ante mano.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola Anny. Si tienes un ejemplo de lo que estás haciendo, sería de utilidad que lo incluyeras en tu pregunta.

Comment: A falta de un ejemplo te explico, en mi caso a nivel de montaje de paquetes ya sea por **inner**(Cantidad en empaque) o piezas(Piezas de un empaque) nosotros sobre cada una de las etiquetas, se crea un TransId que apunta al embalaje y creación de etiqueta lo cual en tu caso van 16 piezas el inner es de 12 la etiqueta seria ejem. PX000100 con TransId 12100 las otras 4 serian PX000101 con TransId 12100 que pertenecen al mismo embalaje con lo cual puedes crear una etiqueta a parte localizando los TransId de cada embalaje ayudandote con campos de usuario en Tablas SAP.

Comment: ntentare hacerme entender con un ejemplo más practico: Tengo una factura con ITEM1 cantidad 16, ITEM2 cantidad 12, ITEM3 cantidad 8 e ITEM4 cantidad 1. La unidad de empaque de todos estos es 16unidades por caja, por tanto deberia imprimir una etiqueta de ITEM1 por 16 unidades, otra etiqueta por ITEM2x12unidades y ITEM3x4 und y una tercera etiqueta con ITEM3x4 y ITEM4X1 unidad, yo ya tengo la parte del codigo que me valida la unidad de empaque por item y funciona pero me generarme picos, es decir deje los item 2, 3 y 4 en etiquera separadas, ¿como puedo administrar estos picos?